# Return a String from a Java action listener

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener, jlabel

This Java application should ask for the users name, and then display text saying 'welcome, name'. Here is my code for the `Main.java`:

```
package NameGui;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame form = new JFrame();
        FlowLayout layout = new FlowLayout();
        JPanel content = new JPanel();

        JPanel top = new JPanel();
        JLabel title = new JLabel();

        JPanel innerForm = new JPanel();
        JLabel inputLabel = new JLabel();
        JTextField input = new JTextField();

        JPanel bottom = new JPanel();
        JButton submit = new JButton();

        JFrame display = new JFrame();
        JLabel nameDisplay = new JLabel();

        Container formContainer = form.getContentPane();
        Container displayContainer = display.getContentPane();

        title.setText("Welcome! What is your name?");
        inputLabel.setText("Name:");
        submit.setText("Submit");
        form.setTitle("Your name");
        display.setTitle("Your name");
        String name = null;

        input.setText("Name Here");
        submit.addActionListener(
            new SwitchScreen(inputLabel, name, display, form));
        top.add(title);

        innerForm.add(inputLabel);
        innerForm.add(input);

        bottom.add(submit);

        content.add(top);
        content.add(innerForm);
        content.add(bottom);

        formContainer.add(content);
        formContainer.setLayout(layout);

        form.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        form.pack();
        form.setVisible(true);

        displayContainer.add(nameDisplay);

        nameDisplay.setText("Your name: " + Aname);
        display.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        display.pack();
        display.setVisible(false);
    }
}
```

And here is the code for the Action Listener:

```
package NameGui;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

class SwitchScreen implements ActionListener
{
    JLabel inputLabel;
    String name;
    JFrame display;
    JFrame form;

    SwitchScreen(JLabel inputLabel, String name, JFrame display, JFrame form)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.inputLabel = inputLabel;
        this.form = form;
        this.display = display;
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
    {
        name = inputLabel.getText();
        form.setVisible(false);
        display.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

When I enter my name into the text box, and then I click submit, it just says 'Welcome, null'.  The actionlistener doesn't seem to be firing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your code has some other mistakes in it, since this won't compile, but assuming you sort those out, you need to update the label that says `"Welcome, " + name`. So instead of saying `name = inputLabel.getText();` try something like `outputField.setText("Welcome, " + inputLabel.getText());`
You'll need to pass whatever the object you want to display the message in to the SwitchScreen object, but that should work.

Another problem you have is that you're passing the JLabel, not the JTextField to the Listener, so even if it was working correctly, the display would be "Welcome, Name:"

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong. You can do that with a single frame like this.

- Our class extends `JFrame` and implements `ActionListener`

  ```
  public class MyGUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener
  {

      public MyGUI()
      {
          super("My Title");
          // Set the close operation to exit
          setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
          // Add the components to the frame
          addComponents();
          // Pack it, show it in center and make it visible
          pack();
          setLocationRelativeTo(null);
          setVisible(true);
      }

  }
  ```
- Now add the UI components as the variables.

  ```
  private JLabel   messageLabel = null;
  private JTextBox textBox      = null;
  private JButton  submitButton = null;
  ```
- Now we make the `addComponents()` method.

  ```
  private void addComponents()
  {
      // Set the layout of the frame
      setLayout(new FlowLayout());
      // Create the components
      messageLabel = new JLabel("Enter your name");
      textBox      = new JTextBox(20);
      submitButton = new JButton("Submit");
      // Add the ActionListener to the submit button
      submitButton.addActionListener(this);
      // Add these components to the frame and pack it
      add(messageLabel);
      add(textBox);
      add(submitButton);
      pack();
  }
  ```
- Now implement the `actionPerformed()` method of the `ActionListener`

  ```
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
  {
      // We've attached it to only one button so no need
      // to check which button the user clicked on.
      messageLabel.setText("Welcome " + textBox.getText() + "!");
      // Remove the textBox and submitButton from the frame
      remove(textBox);
      remove(submitButton);
      // Pack the frame and invalidate it
      pack();
      invalidate();
  }
  ```
- And finally, the `main()` method

  ```
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
      new MyGUI();
  }
  ```

Sorry for a long answer but hope this helped.

Comment: There is no need to initialize fields to null, they are initialized to null by default.